# Is Selenium blocked by HTML comments?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I'm trying to scrape a website that has the following structure:

```
<div>
<!---->
<!---->
<!---->
   <div class="block">
      <h3 class="subtitle is-4"></h3>
      ...
      ...
   </div>
<!---->
</div>
```

But I'm not being able to extract the part between the `<!---->` block. Is Selenium blocked by this particular HTML structure?

[This](https://monitoreo.antai.gob.pa/transparencia/97/6-2023/entregas/2320) is the website I'm trying to scrape

Here's my Python code:

```
def scrape():
        driver = _get_driver()
        driver.get(self.URL)
        driver.maximize_window()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.submission-viewer-card-content div")
            )
        )
        fetch(driver=driver)

def fetch(driver: webdriver):
        css_exp = "div.submission-viewer-card-content div"
        rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_exp)  # type: ignore
        print("rows", rows)
        for row in rows:
            driver.execute_script(  # type: ignore
                "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", row
            )
            print(
                "- text: \n",
                row.text,
                "\n- tag_name: \n",
                row.tag_name,
                "\n- inner HTML: \n",
                row.get_attribute("innerHTML"),
                "\n- element: \n",
                row,
            )
            print("Script execution: ", driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", row))
```

This is the output:

```
rows [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bcee6497731314cd7030e6f9b9b2f823", element="2E7B7723420E954F7D13C37F2AF0EF31_element_45")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bcee6497731314cd7030e6f9b9b2f823", element="2E7B7723420E954F7D13C37F2AF0EF31_element_46")>]
- text: 
 Nombre: Planillas
Descripción: Listado del personal de la entidad con su respectivo salario, código de cargo y otros.
Periodo: 4/2023
Entregado en:
- tag_name:
 div
- inner HTML:
 <p><strong>Nombre:</strong> Planillas</p><p><strong>Descripción:</strong> Listado del personal de la entidad con su respectivo salario, código de cargo y otros.</p><p><strong>Periodo:</strong> 4/2023</p><p><strong>Entregado en:</strong> </p>
- element:
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bcee6497731314cd7030e6f9b9b2f823", element="2E7B7723420E954F7D13C37F2AF0EF31_element_45")>
Script execution:  <p><strong>Nombre:</strong> Planillas</p><p><strong>Descripción:</strong> Listado del personal de la entidad con su respectivo salario, código de cargo y otros.</p><p><strong>Periodo:</strong> 4/2023</p><p><strong>Entregado en:</strong> </p>
- text: 
  
- tag_name:
 div
- inner HTML:
 <!----><!----><!----><!---->
- element:
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bcee6497731314cd7030e6f9b9b2f823", element="2E7B7723420E954F7D13C37F2AF0EF31_element_46")>
Script execution:  <!----><!----><!----><!---->
```

I also have already tried downloading the HTML and using BeautifulSoup afterward to scrape the downloaded HTML but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply scrap comments by using xpath expression `//comment()`

```py
comment_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(your_path_to_comment_in_dom)//comment()')
comment_content = comment_element.get_attribute('textContent')
```

[Reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_comment.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Here's modified code, i did use `input()` to control which moment you will fetch data, because `WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located` doesn't seem to work, so you need to wait until the page is loaded, and then click enter in python terminal:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.URL = url
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    
    def scrape(self):
        self.driver.get(self.URL)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.submission-viewer-card-content div")
            )
        )
        input("Wait until page loads completely, then press enter...")
        self.fetch()

    def fetch(self):
        css_exp = "div.submission-viewer-card-content div"
        rows = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_exp)
        for row in rows:
            self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", row)
            print("- text:\n", row.text,
                  "\n- tag_name:\n", row.tag_name,
                  "\n- inner HTML:\n", row.get_attribute("innerHTML"),
                  "\n- element:\n", row,
                  "\nScript execution:", self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", row))

    def close(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "https://monitoreo.antai.gob.pa/transparencia/97/6-2023/entregas/2320"
    scraper = Scraper(url)
    scraper.scrape()
    scraper.close()
```